# React Router - Returning 404 Conditionally In Components

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

Here is routes setup:

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
  <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
  <Route path="/:subject" component={SubjectPage}/>
  <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
</Route>
```

So every subject param will go to SubjectPage component, where in the component, I check against a predefined array of "valid" subjects to decide whether the page should be rendered. If the subject is not in the array, then I will redirect to error page.

But the problem here is that web server returns success code 200 regardless. This is not good for SEO. What should I do here to make the server return success code 404 for invalid subjects?

Comment: how are you redirecting? you could serve the error page on the server separate from a wildcard and return 404

Comment: just by using browserHistory... i guess i meant forwarding.  From user perspective they wont know, but the status is 202

Comment: don't use browser history then.. use `window.location = '/not_found` or whatever when you want to send 404 back

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to update headers(like Status Code from 200 to 404) in your client side. You have to do this in your backend. This means you need Server Side Rendering (SSR)

See [this tutorial](https://alligator.io/react/react-router-ssr#serving-notfound-using-a-404-status) to setup Server-Side Rendering and learn how to serve NotFound using a 404 status

Comment: you don't need full SSR for this.. just loading a 404 page is enough